# Fill ComboBox with Results of LINQ Query, Directly

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

I am new to c#/.net/WPF.

I am trying to fill a combobox with values taken from a database.

The LINQ query gets a list of all companies in the database and the code attempts to fill a ComboBox control with this list.

The C# code below successfully gets the results (I previously outputted it with a MessageBox.Show()).

My Next step was to remove that bit and, instead, put in the code which would fill out this ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="companyComboBox"/>
```

The c#:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace LeadSystem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NewLead.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NewLead : Window
    {

    public NewLead()
    {


       // Use a connection string.
        DataContext db = new DataContext("Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeadSystem;Integrated Security=True");

        // Get a typed table to run queries.
        Table<Company> Companies = db.GetTable<Company>();

        // Attach the log to show generated SQL.
        db.Log = Console.Out;

        // Query for all companies.
        var companyQuery = 
            from c in Companies
            select new { Name = c.CompanyName, ID = c.CompanyID };

        companyComboBox.ItemsSource = companyQuery.ToList();
        companyComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        companyComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
}
```

The problem I keep getting is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

^ it's talking about companyQuery, where I try to use it to fill the comboBox.

I thought this must be because of deferred execution, and so I had a look around the web to find a solution. I've seen several people say to add ToList() at the end of that line of code, but nothing changed.

So, does someone here know what I'm doing wrong??

I have looked around the web (including Stackoverflow) and nothing has helped me fix mine.

Also, if it's not too cheeky to ask two questions in one go... How do I set the selected value and displayed values in my ComboBox? Is it correct, the way I already have it?

Thanks

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: if you add a breakpoint, can you see if companyQuery returns any results upon enumeration?

Comment: @GlenThomas `companyComboBox.ItemsSource = companyQuery.ToList();`

Comment: @kai - my VS skills are not so great

Comment: As the answers correctly point out, `InitializeComponent()` should be called *before* you use the `ComboBox` in code, but they fail to tell you *why*. The component `companyComboBox` is constructed behind the scenes in that method call. Up until that point, it is `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to fill the companyComboBox after the initializeComponent

```
 InitializeComponent();
    companyComboBox.ItemsSource = companyQuery.ToList();
    companyComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    companyComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
```

Comment: No problem please mark answer as answered to close the question

Answer (score 0):

Put `InitializeComponent();` before you set the `itemSource`